# polymorphic many-to-many on same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User, Tag, and Relationship models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :followers, :as => :followable
    has_many :follows, class_name: "Relationship", :foreign_key => :follower_id
end

class  Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :followers, :as => :followable
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
end
```

A user can follow another User or a Tag. I would like to access the followers for Tag and User, and also find out what users/tags a user follows.

I currently get the following error:

```
2.1.1 :003 > user.followers
NameError: uninitialized constant User::Follower
2.1.1 :005 > tag.followers
NameError: uninitialized constant Tag::Follower
```

Comment: you cannot have follower_id in User since many users can follow a single user.

Comment: also show your current table structure, need to know if your model is right for your needs

Answer (score 0):

add class_name option in you association like:

```
has_many :followers, :as => :followable, class_name: "Relationship"
```

You need to add this because by default rails looks for the matching model name(singular) for you association name.

if you don't want to use `:class_name` then you need to change the name of `Relationship` model to `Follower`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. However I would like user.follows to return User and Tag objects not Relationship objects, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code (I don't know wheither will it work or not):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships, as: followable
   has_many :followers, through: relationships, class_name: :User
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationships, as: followable
   has_many :followers, through: relationships, class_name: :Tag
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and the `Relationship` schema:

```
t.integer :followable_id
t.string :followable_type
```

But I strongly advice to use the [*Single Table Inheritance*](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) instead. And of course if you wish to optimize the db schema, just show as which relations do you want.